# Preencher uma lista com retorno do Json

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Queria preencher uma textarea ou qualquer coisa que se pareça uma lista, com os ítens que o cara seleciona a partir de um dropdow. Então eu pensei assim, mas não sei como alimentar a lista...

```
<textarea cols="1" id="lista">
     <ul>

     </ul>
</textarea>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#Chamada').change(function () {
                        var id = $(Chamada).val();
                        var url = '@Url.Action("MusicaAdc", "Chamada")';
                        $.post(url, { id: id },
                            function (data) {
                                $('#lista').append('<li>"' + value.Nome + '</li>');
                            });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Todos os dados que você irá adicionar na lista são retornados de uma vez só no post, ou conforme o usuário vai selecionando, chamadas diferentes vão sendo feitas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como está o seu json, mas se todos os dados são retornados de uma única vez você pode usar um each para percorre-lo e adicionar linha por linha na tabela value deve retornar o valor dentro do each, se for uma string você usa só o value para mostrar, caso seja um array use value["Nome"]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Chamada').change(function () {
          var id = $(Chamada).val();
          var url = '@Url.Action("MusicaAdc", "Chamada")';
          $.post(url, { id: id },
          function (data) {
               $.each(data, function(index, value){
                       $('#lista').append('<li>"' + value["Nome"] + '</li>');
                });
           }
      });
});
```